# How to filter based on date in certain cases in SQL?

Tags: mysql, date

So let's say I have data like this:

```
 ID   GROUP               TIMESTAMP1    col_OTHER               TIMESTAMP2
001      AA  2021-04-02 15:02:33.319       mangos
002      BB                                 kiwis
004      AA  2021-04-02 03:51:35.279      oranges
003      DD  2021-04-03 18:24:23.469      oranges  2021-04-03 18:22:23.469 
003      DD                               bananas  2021-04-03 15:02:33.319
002      CC  2021-04-04 11:02:51.313       apples  2021-04-04 11:03:51.313
```

So I want to filter just the rows where `TIMESTAMP2` is after `TIMESTAMP1` . We only started collecting data on `TIMESTAMP2` April 3, no nulls after this but we have no data on this prior. So I want to apply this condition after this date.

Additionally we sometimes have null values in `TIMESTAMP1`, I think my coalesce() solves that...?

Final output:

```
 ID   GROUP               TIMESTAMP1    col_OTHER               TIMESTAMP2
001      AA  2021-04-02 15:02:33.319       mangos
002      BB                                 kiwis
004      AA  2021-04-02 03:51:35.279      oranges 
003      DD                               bananas  2021-04-03 15:02:33.319
002      CC  2021-04-04 11:02:51.313       apples  2021-04-04 11:03:51.313
```

And here's what I have thus far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dt
WHERE coalesce(TIMESTAMP1, '1970-01-01') < TIMESTAMP2
```

I would also be curious how to remove instances where I have NULL in both TIMESTAMP1 and TIMESTAMP2

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dt
WHERE COALESCE(TIMESTAMP1, '1970-01-01') < '2021-04-03'
   OR COALESCE(TIMESTAMP1, '1970-01-01') < TIMESTAMP2
```

or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dt
WHERE COALESCE(TIMESTAMP1, '1970-01-01') < COALESCE(TIMESTAMP2, '2021-04-03')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f5bd764e27c5969f5ffbaa6a88c7d2e1).
Results:

| ID | GROUP | TIMESTAMP1 | col_OTHER | TIMESTAMP2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | AA | 2021-04-02 15:02:33.319 | mangos | null |
| 002 | BB | null | kiwis | null |
| 004 | AA | 2021-04-02 03:51:35.279 | oranges | null |
| 003 | DD | null | bananas | 2021-04-03 15:02:33.319 |
| 002 | CC | 2021-04-04 11:02:51.313 | apples | 2021-04-04 11:03:51.313 |

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM dt
    WHERE TIMESTAMP1 is not null and TIMESTAMP2 is not null and TIMESTAMP1 < TIMESTAMP2
```